# SQL 2005 32-bit - Memory for Instances

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005, memory, 32-bit

We have a SQL Server 2K5 installation on a Windows 2003 R2 server with eight cores and 16GB of RAM.  While it's in our plan to upgrade it to 64-bit, for now we are on the 32-bit version.

Currently we have one instance set to use all available memory, but need to run two instances.  Given that this is 32-bit and this would be two separate SQL2K5 instances, would I have two instances contending for the first 4GB, or would they both be able to address 4GB+?

Thanks!
-Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need SQL 2005 Enterprise Edition for using AWE - Standard will work fine. See this [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175581(SQL.90).aspx) link.

Comment: You are right of course Paul. My fault, i went on this page but i stop reading after the "enterprise" word, like an idiot

Answer (score 0):

They can both use more than 4GB. But:

- You need PAE activated (/PAE in boot.ini)
- You need Windows enterprise at least
- You need enterprise SQL Server Version
- all memory > 4GB will be used only as cache. Can't use to store objects & co

You should go 64 bit as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  We're on SQL2K5 standard, Windows 2003 Enterprise.  What effect does being on SQL2K5 standard have on this problem?